# How to parallelize a computation?

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, ode

I am trying to compute a ordinary ODE (ordinary differential equation) on a distance matrix but I do not know how to parallelize my code.

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from math import exp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#I have my distance matrix and I wanna count how many points are distanced
# from point i with distance r at maximum 
def v(dist, r, i):
    return 1/N*(np.count_nonzero(np.select([dist[i,:]<r],[dist[i,:]]))+1)
#integral of rho from r to infinity
def rho_barre(rho, r):
    return quad(rho, r, np.inf)
# integral over r of a certain integrand
def grad_F(i, j, rho, v, v_r, dist):
    return quad(lambda r : ((v(dist, r, i)+v(dist, r, j))/2-v_r)*rho_barre(rho, max(r, dist[i,j])), 0, np.inf) 

#parameters
delta_T = 0.1
rho = (lambda x: exp(-x))
v_r =0

for t in range (1000):
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            d_matrix[i,j] = d_matrix[i,j] + delta_T* grad_F(i,j,rho, v, v_r, d_matrix)
```

First I have the following error `can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'` that I don't understand why. Then, I know that three loops are too much in python and I want to know how can we make it faster in Python.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have a few different questions. Let me see if I can answer more abstractly and you can piece it together

#### Parallel

One very easy easy way to work in parallel in Python is `multiprocessing`

If you apply the same function many times, instead of:

```
res = [myfun(arg) for arg in args]
```

you can do:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
with mp.Pool() as pool:
    res = pool.map(myfun,args)
```

There are limitations. Both `myfun` and `args` must be pickleable (which `lambda` is *not* so you will want to address that in your code)

#### Nested Loops

In general, python loops are slow. When working with NumPy, it is better to "vectorize" if you can.

So instead of woking on each `[i,j]` element of `d_matrix`, see if you can work on them all at the same time. So compute a *matrix* `grad_F` (rather than a function) and add it. You will still need your time loop but you may be able to solve your `d_matrix` in a single, very fast, action.

#### Other tips:

Can you precompute `rho_barre`. Maybe use `scipy.integrate.cumtrapz` to compute that?

Also, try to write fewer one-liners. Use new functions instead of lambdas. It will make understanding your code much easier!